# Android SharedPreferences unsorted set

Tags: android, arrays, list, set, sharedpreferences

I want to save a list of strings to a SharedPreferences object. I use these methods but if a set is (2,1,3) when I read it the list is (1,2,3). I don't want to sort the set when I read the array.

EDIT: When I use getSharedPreferences the set is already sorted inside the sharedPreferences object.

```
private List<String> load() {
    Set<String> values = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(PREF_KEY, null);
    return new ArrayList<String>(values);
}

private void save(List<String> values) {
    //values = (2,1,3)
    Set<String> valuesSet = new HashSet<String>(values);
    //valuesSet = (1,2,3)
    sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putStringSet(PREF_KEY, valuesSet).commit();
}
```

Comment: Read [documentation of HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). > This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). **It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.** This class permits the null element.

Comment: My problem is that when I do getSharedPreferences() the set is sorted inside the sharedPreferences object.

Comment: Are you getting that sorted values *every time*? Check rerunning application for 3-4 times and see values.

Comment: Yes I checked at debug time.

Comment: when you add HashSet to shared preference, **your order will NEVER been guaranteed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use serialisation:

```
private void save(List<String> values) {
    String serialisedString = ObjectSerializer.serialize(values);

    sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putString(PREF_KEY, serialisedString).commit();
}


private List<String> load() {
    String serialisedString = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>()));
    ArrayList<String> retrievedValues = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize();

    return retrievedValues;    
}
```

Comment: There is no ObjectSerializer in android.

Comment: Find it [here](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

Comment: Or any other json library, like org.json.